# CMFCRibbonEdit does not get focus

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I just added a CMFCRibbonEdit to my ribbon but it seems it does not get the focus.

It appears disabled.

I even copy/pasted an implementation of the creation of this control from a Microsoft sample but I get the same behaviour.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong or forgetting to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added an update handler for that ribbon element ID?

Check the [RibbonGadgets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982410.aspx) and [MSOffice2007Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984334.aspx) samples in the MFC Feature Pack to see how they do it.

The RibbonGadgets one will show you the exact code you need to use in order to add an element of the specified type to your ribbon.

Comment: As mentioned I copy/pasted code from these two examples.
I just copied the creation code.
You talk about an update handler, could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

democodemonkey though it correctly. The ribbon elements need to all have an update handler, even a dummy one.
If they do not they are disabled.

Now everything work perfectly.

Comment: But how to get the OnKillFocus event of the CMFCRibbonEdit

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the CEditRiBbbon

class CMFCRibbonEditEx : public CMFCRibbonEdit
{
public:
    CMFCRibbonEditEx(UINT nID, int nWidth, LPCTSTR lpszLabel = NULL, int nImage = -1) 
        : CMFCRibbonEdit(nID, nWidth, lpszLabel, nImage) {}
        virtual ~CMFCRibbonEditEx() {}

```
    void SetControlFocus()
    {
        m_pWndEdit->SetFocus();
    }
```

};

use the CMFCRibbonEditEx  instead of CMFCRibbonEdit